# Apache connected but still got a strange message when I start server

Tags: php, apache, symfony, mamp

I just installed MAMP3 and got the following message: **"Apache cannot start because PORT 1000 already used by an other application."**

I don't understand and that make no sense because the PORT used is "8889" for Apache.

Moreover Apache server seems to be working... but not SQL server. Anyone has experienced this error?

Comment: You must have installed an Apache with port 8889.

Comment: [Install Apache, PHP, and MySQL on Mac OS X](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2014/11/install-apache-php-mysql-mac-os-x-yosemite/) the *right way*.

Comment: zairwolf. What do you mean. I haven't desinstalled my old MAMP. Just renamed the folder MAMP OLD in my Application forlder. could it have an impact? how can I desinstalled then an Apache port 8889